# Line-by-line indentation control with memoir class

Tags: memoir, indentation

I'm having trouble controlling the indentation of individual lines while maintaining hanging indentation at each level. It's a bit hard for me to describe so I think it'll be clearest with a picture:
[image: Example text with hanging indentation within lines and hierarchical indentation across lines]

There are two things making it difficult:

1. there are a lot of long lines, so hanging indentation is a must
2. there are a lot of places where the hierarchical indentation goes 3 or 4 levels in, so it's not feasible for every hanging indent to land in the same place.

The closest I've gotten is by using `patverse` in the `verse` environment that comes with `memoir`, but that only lets me offset the first line of each new indented portion; all the wrapped text lines up in a way that makes it impossible to indent twice or more:
[image: Text example where text wraps to the second level of indentation]

I've considered using nested `description` environments, but I want the inter-line spacing to be the same as regular text. That could probably be fixed, but it seems like a a bit of a hassle to actually use, so I wanted to know if there was something better before I tried getting it to work.

One last thing: for now, I'm planning to use the `memoir` package. If that makes this indentation scheme overly complicated to mark up, I'm willing to let it go, but ideally I'd like a solution that works nicely with `memoir`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. These look like nested lists but with no labels. Would that be an adequate way to enter them? This is fairly simple to to with `enumitem`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think so. I didn't know about `enumitem` but that seems like it would make it easy to fix the vertical spacing with `description`s.

Comment: Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it. Why do you expect us to guess/invent what you might have done? --- GOM

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version just using an `itemize` environment with minimal settings created using the `enumitem` package. There's no need to use a `description` environment because you have no label at all, so `itemize` is the most appropriate. You can play with the settings as you like to get the spacing you want. I've used the `nosep` key to remove all vertical spacing from the list, and set the top level margin to be flush with the rest of the text.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{nolabel}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[nolabel]{label={},nosep,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=0pt}
\setlist*[nolabel,1]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{nolabel}
\item This is a line at the first level of the list. Here’s how it wraps when the line is very long:
\begin{nolabel}
    \item This is a line at the second level of the list.
    \item This is another line at the second level.
    \begin{nolabel}
        \item This is a third level item.
        \item This a another third level item.
    \end{nolabel}
    \item This is a third second level item.
    \end{nolabel}
\item This is a final first level item.
\end{nolabel}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]